# Checking response of google reCAPTCHA

Tags: php, recaptcha

I am sending google recaptcha and getting response object

```
stdClass Object
(
[success] => 1
[challenge_ts] => 2016-03-01T18:15:36Z
[hostname] => localhost
)
```

How do i get the value of success to see if it was 1

PS: Value name is $response.I tried doing if($response["success"] === true) did not work.

Comment: Could you post your PHP snippet of the method containing the conditional statement? Have you tried echo-ing the value of `$response["success"]`?

Comment: I did try that it said: Cannot use object of type stdClass

Comment: `$response->success`

Comment: Thank you so much @u_mulder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following your comments, it is clear that the response is an object, not an array.

You would therefore have to use

```
$response->success;
```

instead of

```
$response["success"];
```